# where can i find the logs of ionic and Loopback

Tags: ionic-framework, loopbackjs

i want log files of the Loopback server where everthing is recorded

Comment: you question is not clear. what you are trying to do?

Comment: all want is the log files where all activities of the loop-back server are recorded